# CKEditor doesn't show content

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ckeditor

I have problem with CKEditor. I use setData() method to put content into editor. It works, but only first time I display it. When I click back button in the browser and try to open this view or another once again editor is displayed but no content is in it although the data were returned from database. Have you any ideas how can I resolve this problem? 
This is my init method which is invoked in ng-init directive:

```
  $scope.initCKEEditor = function() {
        CKEDITOR.replace('questionEditor', {
            uiColor: '#C0B9B9',
            height: 100,
            toolbarCanCollapse: true,
            skin: 'kama'
        });
    };
```

And this is my method to getting question content from database:

```
$scope.getQuestionContent = function() {
        Database.get("SELECT question_content FROM `question` WHERE question_ID = "
            + $scope.idQuestion, function(response) {
            CKEDITOR.instances['questionEditor'].setData(response[0].question_content);
        });
 };
```

Comment: How is the data getting set? You didn't provide code for your data or where you set it. You could be losing a value in the scope and we wouldn't be able to tell.

Comment: Also this is a great example of using CKEditor in AngularJS, http://jsfiddle.net/thesharpieone/cptr7/